# reading excel file in c#

Tags: c#, excel

is there any way to read the dates in excel as just normal string and not as dates? i'm making an application in c# where i could read and view all the data inside the excel. when i view the datas, the dates are in this format: mm:dd:yyyy hh:mm:ss.

this is my code in reading the excel

```
            if (filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf('.')).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
            {
                strConn = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;""", filePath);
            }
            else
            {
                strConn = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;'", filePath);
            }

            string sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$A5:AG]", sheetname);
            OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, strConn);
            adap.Fill(dset);
```

Comment: your date field .toString() ?

Comment: "Not a legal OleAut date".this is the error that i always get when i read an excel file